# CSS custom font vertical offset (bug?)

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

I use custom font in my CSS with this method:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gabriola';
    src: url('Gabriola.eot');
    src: url('Gabriola.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Gabriola.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Gabriola.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.gabriola {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

<div class="gabriola">Some texty text here</div>
```

Each browser renders this fonts by it's own way with vertical offset top and bottom like this
[image: font rendering]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here, but have you tried using a `span` instead? (or any other inline element instead of a block one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible there is not anything you are doing wrong. Here are some points that may apply, some controllable by you, some not.

1. Just to be sure, explicitly set `vertical-align: baseline`.
2. The different files (`.eof`, `.woff`, `.ttf`) themselves may not be defined the same, and thus different browsers are using different files and displaying differences.
3. Not sure if having two `src` calls is messing things up, but you can try eliminating the second one:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gabriola';
    src: url('Gabriola.eot'),
         url('Gabriola.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Gabriola.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Gabriola.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

These are all mere guesses. You will have to test #1, 3. If the issue is #2, I'm not sure there is an elegant solution.

There is, of course, the caveat on [this site](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/):

> Keep in mind that **font rendering can vary widely across browsers and
>   operating systems**. Many developers have experienced such poor results
>   from Windows and Internet Explorer that they avoid using custom fonts
>   altogether. Always be sure to examine your results closely on all the
>   browsers that you can to decide if the quality is acceptable.

**Update**

[This post](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/forum/discussion/159/font-face-rendering-problems-generated-fonts-dont-look-correct/p1) gives some tips about possibly resolving rendering issues. This is for Font Squirrel, and he specifically notes:

> If you downloaded the kit, you might try regenerating the font with
>   the generator. We make periodic adjustments to the generator that
>   might improve the hinting or rendering of the font.

But he also confirms,

> Not to pass the buck, but the most common cause is a bad original
>   font.

Which goes with my point #2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. the reason why it is not the same in all browser is the font. I tried 5 font types but only Gabriola has the vertical offset bug. So I suppose it's all about the font 'quality'.

Comment: Point 3 is wrong. Explorer always uses the last font file so we need two separate `src`.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's been 5 years since the OP asked the question, but I found this great technique on getting text baseline-aligned correctly.

Basically, the text container must be an inline-block with line-height: 0;
Then, you create an inline-block pseudo-element and set its height according to the line-height you wanted:

```css
span {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: red;
}
span.baseline-align {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

span.true-baseline-align {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}
span.true-baseline-align::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em; // this is where you control line-height
}
```

```html
<span>Normal text</span>
<br><br>
<span class="baseline-align">With vertical-align: baseline</span>
<br><br>
<span class="true-baseline-align">with trick to really baseline-align</span>
```

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/08/13/one-weird-trick-to-baseline-align-text/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15705140)

Comment: Thanks! I changed my answer :)

Comment: this is sooooo genious! thanks for sharing this little hack :)

Comment: Caution that this solution only works on single lines.  If your sentence spans more than one line (likely with responsive nature of the web) then it will overlap itself.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution if anyone has the issue and do not want or cannot reconstruct the font:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/ascent-override

This prop will adjust the vertical ascend property when the font is imported.

Comment: Thanks, man – this is the 2022 answer to this question!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution was to reconstruct the font with the properties of the original without changing anything in a new file with Hight logic font creator, the font is unchanged and equal to the original problem is corrected and aligned to the perfection in all browsers including ie6, was the work of a few hours but this is the result in case you need some user.

http://www.filefactory.com/file/1miw29cddg21/n/crossbrowser_gabriola_font.zip

Comment: Are you saying that you opened the font in "Height logic font creator" and adjusted the spacing for each letter, or that you simply opened the font and re-exported it using that application?

Comment: (Consider using multiple sentences)